# Weird error using C++/CLI - Cannot convert from parameter type to same parameter type

Tags: c++-cli

I've got the following code:

```cpp
vlib_stage_decoding_config_t Decoder::CfgTransform(const DecodingConfig config)
{
    vlib_stage_decoding_config_t cfg;
    return cfg;
}

void Decoder::OpenDecode(const DecodingConfig config)
{
    vlib_stage_decoding_config_t int_cfg = CfgTransform(config);
    vlib_stage_decoding_open(&int_cfg);
}
```

Header file:

```cpp
public ref struct DecodingConfig
{
};
```

I get the following error:

> Error  1   error C2664: `'Video::Decoding::Decoder::CfgTransform'` : cannot convert parameter 1 from `'const Video::Decoding::DecodingConfig'` to `'const Video::Decoding::DecodingConfig'`    decoder.cpp

This is pretty nonsensical to me. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ares it's `vlib_stage_decoding_config_t int_cfg = CfgTransform(config);`. Pretty weird IMHO.

Comment: Is DecodingConfig really an empty struct? If not, the contents can possibly cause this error, especially if you have a ref class member inside DecodingConfig. Can you post the contents of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cpp
vlib_stage_decoding_config_t Decoder::CfgTransform(DecodingConfig^ config)
{
    vlib_stage_decoding_config_t cfg;
    return cfg;
}

void Decoder::OpenDecode(DecodingConfig^ config)
{
    vlib_stage_decoding_config_t int_cfg = CfgTransform(config);
    vlib_stage_decoding_open(&int_cfg);
}
```

1. `const` is meaningless for managed types.
2. Despite your use of `struct`, `DecodingConfig` is a reference type, not a value type, so it cannot be passed without a tracking handle or a tracking reference. If you want `DecodingConfig` to be a value type, use `value struct` instead of `ref struct` and get rid of the `^`s in your function arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new to managed c++ unfortunately, and the error didn't hint at anything really. So thanks!